# Set compiler option to default In CMake

Tags: cmake, visual-c++-2008

How can I set "Basic Runtime Checks" to "Default" in my CMake file?

With following line in CMake, I can set it to RTCs in Release mode, but what I really need is set it to Default.

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} /RTCs")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

Use macro to delete the current compiler option.

```
macro(RemoveDebugCXXFlag flag)
    string(REPLACE "${flag}" "" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG}")
endmacro()

macro(RemoveReleaseCXXFlag flag)
    string(REPLACE "${flag}" "" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE}")
endmacro()

message(${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG}) # Print Debug Flags Before Change
RemoveDebugCXXFlag("/RTC1")

message(${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG}) # Print Debug Flags After Change

message(${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE}) # Print Release Flags Before Change
RemoveReleaseCXXFlag("/RTC1")
message(${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE}) # Print Release Flags After Change
```

Best Regards

Comment: Just wanted to suggest a more generic version by making part of the variable name also variable: `foreach(config ${CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES})` | `string(TOUPPER "${config}" CONFIG)` | `string(REGEX REPLACE "/RTC[A-Za-z0-9]*" "" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_${CONFIG} "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_${CONFIG}}")` | `message("${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_${CONFIG}}")` | `endforeach()`.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion Florian